# Why the java array documentation doesn't show the field "length"?

Tags: java, arrays, field

I have seen some examples of getting the length of an array using the field length, for example: array.length. I have always used this field but checking the array documentation I did not see that variable. Why is it that the documentation doesn't show it? It only shows a bunch of methods but I can't see the variable length. Is it in another class or what? I have seen questions like this before but the answers are not well explained so I can't understand them.

Comment: Which array documentation are you referring to?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

Comment: That's a class to manipulate arrays, just like its docs say.

Comment: Then there isn't a class that shows what actually an array is and all of its members and methods?

Comment: No, and class `java.lang.reflect.Array` is not the actual class of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Because length is not actually a field.  The compiler recognizes the identifier specially and translates it to an `arraylength` instruction rather than a `getfield` instruction.